# std::string::erase() segfaults when given an iterator

Tags: c++11, stl

I have a string-

```
std::string out;
```

and an iterator over that string-

```
std::string::iterator pos = out.begin();
```

if I do -

```
if(!out.empty() || pos > out.begin())
  out.erase(pos--);
```

It segfaults, with this error-

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
            __memmove_ssse3 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S:2821
2821    ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S: No such file or directory.
```

What am I missing?

For some context, I'm implementing line editing with ncurses and this code defines behaviour when backspace is pressed.

***EDIT***

It segfaults even after I move the decrement out of the call.

here is an MCVE -

```
#include <string>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{

  initscr();
  cbreak();
  keypad(stdscr, true);                           //Seems to be causing the error
  std::string out;
  std::string::iterator pos = out.begin();
  short ch;
  bool insert = false;
  int y, x;

  while(true)
  {
    ch = getch();                                 //Get next character

    if(ch == '\n')
      break;                                      //End of line

    else if(ch == KEY_BACKSPACE)                  //Backspace behaviour defined here
    {
      if(!out.empty())
      {
        out.erase(pos);                           //Character erased from string as per backspace
        addch('\b');                              //Erasure reflected on screen
        std::string temp(pos, out.end());         //
        getyx(stdscr, y, x);
        mvaddstr(y, x - 1, temp.c_str());
      }
    }

    else if(std::isalnum(ch) || std::ispunct(ch)) //Normal characters
    {
      if(!insert)                                 //If insert is off
        out.insert(pos++, ch);                    //Character inserted normally
      else                                        //Insert is on
      {
        *pos = ch;                                //Overwrite characters
        pos++;
      }
    }
  }
  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

Compile with

```
g++ -lncurses -std=c++11
```

`-Wall` gives no clues.

Comment: What is "it" that segfaults? Is it the compiler or your program? Segfaults don't usually mention about the non existence of any file in my experience. Are you sure that it was a segfault?

Comment: the program. I'll edit the question with the full error.

Comment: I'm guessing that the missing file is just a warning that is not directly part of the segmentation fault. I suggest creating a [mcve] that reproduces the segfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour for std::string. In the C++ standard, validity of string iterators is not garanteed after a modification of the string, contrary to other types with stronger requirements.

In [string.require] (§21.4.1), the standard states:

> References, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of a
>   basic_­string sequence may be invalidated by the following uses of
>   that basic_­string object: [...] Calling non-const member functions,
>   except operator[], at, data, front, back, begin, rbegin, end, and
>   rend.

Comment: So I would need to reassign pos?

Comment: Yes exactly, since it may be invalidated after any modification of out. But actually, a simpler and more elegant solution in your case could be to use an index rather than an iterator for pos.